# Rank and nullity of a Linear transformation involving Polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $f:\Re_{3}[x] \rightarrow \Re_{4}[x]$

such as

$f(p(x))=xp(x)$  for any $x \in \Re_{3}[x]$

Determine if the next polynomials belong to the rank of $f$ and if they belong to the nullity of $f$.

$a) x^3$

I'm confused about this.

We have that $f(x)=xp(x)$ so

$f(x^2)=xx^2=x^3$? I don't quite get how to do it.
From the solutions it says

$x^3 \in Im f$ and $x^3 \notin Nuc f$

But isn't $x^3=0 (=) x=0?$ How come its not in $Nuc f?$

(Note: I'm trying to be better on the site, so if I should edit anything or am not being clear, I accept criticism.)

Comment: What do you denote $Nuc f$?

Comment: $Nuc f$ in the nullity.

Comment: Recall that an element, say $v$, of a vector space $V$, belongs to the nullity of a linear function $L\colon V\to W$ (where $W$ is also a vector space) if $L(v)=0_W$. In this problem you have $L=f$, $V=\Re_{3}[x]$  and $W=\Re_{4}[x]$. In your question we're considering $v=x^3$. Now a question for you, what is $0_W$ and why? If you can answer this question, you can answer yours.

Comment: Does it have to do with $0_{W}=(0,0,0,0)$ and $ 0_{V}=(0,0,0)$?

Comment: Oh! So  $Nuc f$ is just $\ker f$?

Comment: Yes, In portugal we call it "Nucleous of f", my bad xD

Comment: @Jakcjones Not really, my question is independent of $V$. In any vector space $W$ you have an element you denote by $0_W$, it must have certain properties in order for it to be entitled with the notation of $0_W$. What are these properties for $\Re_{4}[x]$, specifically?

Answer (score 1):

Let $F: R_n[x] \rightarrow R_{n+1}[x]$

By definition a vector [polynomial] P belongs to the kernel if $F(P)=0$
Here we have $F(x^3)=x^4$ which is a nonzero polynomial, hence $x^3$ doesn't lie in the kernel.

If we want to check wether a vector [polynomial] $P$ belongs to the image we have to check if there is such a vector [polynomial] $W$ such that $F(W)=P$
Here: $F(W)=xW=x^3 \rightarrow W=x^2$ ; By definition $x^3$ lies in the image.